# Javascript Formula to convert WGS84 lat, long values to RD_New co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, angular16, wgs84, esri-maps

I have a requirement in my project to convert WDS84 GPS format co-ordinates to RD_New co-ordinates

```
WGS84(E,N): 51.998929,4.375587
RD(X,Y):    85530,446100
```

I see some online tools and Proj4 js libraries to so this conversion.
But i need some Formula so i can directly convert values in my Angular project.

Below link converts from RD_New to WDS84.
http://www.aukema.org/2020/02/convert-dutch-rd-coordinates-to-wgs-84.html

I couldn't find Formula for RD_New conversion

Comment: Try posting on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead as this question is not related to stackoverflow, rather a question for geographic information systems.

Comment: I believe you can find the formula starting on page 62 with the RD constants provided on 63.  The "reverse" calculation you're looking for has an example on page 64
https://web.archive.org/web/20130605232655/http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/g7-2.pdf

Comment: I have posted in gis.stackexchange as advised. @possum I have gone thro the PDF but the formula seems to be confusing. Can it be elaborated / example provided ?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  They're probably confusing because they require iterative solutions because it's a nonlinear equation.  You're going to be up against this in your own implementation.  I'm not sure what to tell you because I would just reiterate what you were given.  *This is why using a third party solution is recommended*

Comment: ok @possum. Apart from using 3rd party library do we have any API in arcgis server to do this conversion. So we just call the API with lat, long values and they send converted RD co-ordinates ?

Comment: There is a http://proj4js.org/ library.  Why not just use that in your angular app?  Yes if you want to use an API that's fine too.  This is getting outside of the scope of your question

Comment: Thanks @possum. I will explore on proj4js.org library.